# Inserting Custom object as pointer in Parse. [Error]: objectId is an invalid field name

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a Product object that I get form database in Parse. So I am trying to create UserFavourites object, that has user_id and the Product object, that already in Parse database.

This is the code:

```
PFObject *product = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Product"];
    product[@"objectId"] = @"8gFcLQ3oZo";
    userFavourite[@"product"] = product;
    userFavourite[@"user"] = [[PFUser currentUser] objectId];
    [userFavourite saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            // The object has been saved.
        } else {
            // There was a problem, check error.description
        }
    }];
```

I took those values that I assign, form db. This is just for testing.
However, I get the error:

```
[Error]: objectId is an invalid field name (Code: 105, Version: 1.7.1)
```

This is because of I am setting objectId. But when I remove this like, for setting objectId, the Product object gets inserted to Product table as new object (dublicating exisitng one, but with new objectId).
I thought that I need to specify objectId, so that it would not get inserted as new object.
So, what is the right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What happens if you try [product setObjectId:@"myId"];

Comment: @Frankie, it works ))) why did not I try that myself?)) Thank you very much)

Comment: I don't think this is the best way of doing this. Will you always have the object id of the object you want to modify available?

Comment: Glad it worked!  I've added my comment as an official answer so that you can have a chance to accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `objectId` as so:

```
 [product setObjectId:@"myId"];
```